# how to add -fvisibility=hidden in configure

Tags: gcc, makefile, configure

In compiling opencv project, I need to hidden all their interfaces, so I need to add a compile option "-fvisibility=hidden" to configure when generating Makefile for opencv.

The question is, how to add the compile option to configure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting CFLAGs, e.g.:

```
CFLAGS="-fvisibility=hidden" ./configure
```